# Sind Pflanzennamen oder Musikinstrumente Eigennamen?

Tags: noun

Bei Gesellschaftsspielen, in denen es um Sprache geht, gibt es oft die Einschränkung, dass man keine Eigennamen verwenden darf (Bsp. Scrabble). Gehören dazu eigentlich auch Pflanzennamen wie Salbei und Thymian? Oder Musikinstrumente wie Gitarre oder Xylophon?

Comment: Wenn das so wäre - was wäre denn dann kein Eigenname? Die Frage ist eigentlich nicht an die dt. Sprache gebunden und gehört eher nach Dingens, Languages & Ähnliches.

Comment: @userunknown meinst du vielleicht [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: @Vogel612: Linguistics, Du sagst es!

Answer (score 2):

Nein. Auch Gefäßnamen wie Eimer, Beutel, Krug und Fass sind keine Eigennamen. Jeder Begriff ist ein Name für ein Objekt, soweit es sich um Substantive handelt.

Answer (score 2):

Erstmal sind Definitionen ja kein reiner Selbstzweck und es gibt meines Wissens kaum etwas Wichtiges, für das es nötig ist, eine saubere Grenze zwischen Eigennamen und allem anderen zu finden – es sei denn, man zählt Scrabble und Rechtschreibung. Daher dürfte es auch keine allgemein akzeptierte Definition geben, die über alle Fälle zweifelsfrei entscheidet, insbesondere im Deutschen, wo es rechtschreibtechnisch weit weniger relevant ist als in anderen Sprachen, ob etwas ein Eigenname ist – erst recht bei den Zweifelsfällen. (Und auch bei Scrabble u. Ä. ist das Eigennamenkriterium ja kein reiner Selbstzweck, sondern dient dazu, zu vermeiden, dass jemand das Spiel nur dank seiner umfassenden Kenntnis der vielen Eigennamen gewinnt, die nun mal in Wörterbüchern vertreten sind und in solchen Spielen sehr hilfreich sein könnten. Im den meisten anderen Sprachen kann man dieses Kriterium übrigens einfach durch ein Groß- und Kleinschreibungskriterium ersetzen.)

Wenn Du eine Definition brauchst: *Begriffe, die fest einem individuellen Ding zugewiesen sind.* Dabei kann es sich bei *Ding* um Personen (Cäsar, Angela Merkel), feste Gruppen von Personen (die Beatles), geographische Entitäten (Hamburg, Deutschland, die Alpen, die Elbe), Kunstwerke (Metropolis, die Bibel) usw. handeln. Aber auch das dürfte nicht in allen Fällen für Scrabble o. Ä. befriedigend sein: *Die Sonne* bezeichnet ja z. B. genauso einen individuellen Stern wie *Beteigeuze* und trotzdem würden die meisten wohl nur ersteres beim Scrabble zulassen. (Bei Scrabble o. Ä. werden in der Regel auch noch nach einem festen Schema aus Eigennamen abgeleitete Begriffe verboten, wie z. B. *deutsch, Deutscher, ohmsch* oder *kafkaesk*).

In jedem Fall würde ich Pflanzennamen nicht hinzuzählen, denn es wird kein Individuum identifiziert. Hier könnte man höchstens argumentieren, dass *Thymian* eine individuelle Pflanzengattung bezeichnet – allerdings kann es auch als Singularetantum für jede Anhäufung von Thymian stehen. Bei Musikinstrumenten fiele mir höchstens das [Theremin](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin) ein, aber auch dieses bezeichnet kein individuelles Instrument. (Zur Vermeidung exotischer Pflanzen-, Tier- oder Musikinstrumentnamen bei Scrabble sei darauf verwiesen, dass die Wörterbuchregel nicht nur dazu dient, die Rechtschreibung sicherzustellen.)

Answer (score 0):

**No.** I assume that both are common nouns (**Gattungsnamen** / Apellativa)

Provided that wikipedia is correct on this:

> Ein **Eigenname**, auch Nomen proprium, bezeichnet einzelne Dinge oder Wesen. Eigennamen bilden eine eigene Klasse von Wörtern. Zusammen mit den **Gattungsnamen** (Appellativa) und den **Stoffnamen** (Kontinuativa) **bilden** sie **die Nomina** (Namen im allgemeinen Sinne)
>   <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname</sub>